# Using NotePad++ To Replace Text With Filename?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, ssh, notepad++

I have several hundred files that I need to bulk replace text in.

I know that in NotePad++ I can use "Find in Files" and bulk replace the text in all the files at once.  I need to replace `YYYYYYYYY` from each file with the name of that specific file.

Is there any way to do this using their Extended or Regular Expression search modes?

Also, I have the the shortkey `CTRL + D` setup to automatically copy the filename in case that helps...

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm also open to doing this via shell if that's easier...

Answer (score 5):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/Y{9}/$ARGV/g' file1 file2 file3
```

Or with windows quoting:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/Y{9}/$ARGV/g" file1 file2 file3
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s/Y{9}/.../g`: Search and replace for 9 consecutive Y's
- [`$ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html): Contains the name of the current file when reading from `<>`.

If you want to apply this to many files without explicitly listing them, you can use:

```
perl -i -pe 's/Y{9}/$ARGV/g' *.py
```

And you can achieve this indirectly on windows using a [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
perl -i.bak -pe "BEGIN {@ARGV = glob('*.py')} s/Y{9}/$ARGV/g"
```